# Why is my pandas dataframe data type turning into 'None' type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

I am working with data frame while after running the specific code and check for head() function I got the error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'
"

The relevant piece of code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
rfilepath="Advertising.csv"
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def loaddata(rfilepath):
    data=pd.read_csv(rfilepath)
    return(data)

try:
    data_df=loaddata(rfilepath)
    print(data_df)
except:
    print("error")


data_df.head() #Here no error is showing



def processdata(data_df):
    for (columnName, columnData) in data_df.iteritems():


        print(columnName)
        sns.boxplot(data_df[columnName])
        plt.show()
        q1=stats.scoreatpercentile(data_df[columnName],25)
        print("Q1",q1)

        q3=stats.scoreatpercentile(data_df[columnName],75)
        print("Q3",q3)

        iqr=stats.iqr(data_df[columnName])
        print("iqr",iqr)

        lower_bound= q1- 1.5*(iqr)
        print("Lowebound",lower_bound)

        upper_bound= q3+ 1.5*(iqr)
        print("upperbound",upper_bound)
        print("\n")
        outliers= data_df[columnName][((data_df[columnName]<lower_bound) | (data_df[columnName]>upper_bound))]
        outliers
        median=stats.scoreatpercentile(data_df[columnName],99)
        median
        for i in outliers:
            data_df[columnName]=np.where(data_df[columnName]==i,median,data_df[columnName])
        sns.boxplot(data_df[columnName])
        plt.show()


try:
    data_df=processdata(data_df)
except:
    print("error")

data_df.head()#after calling the function processdata(data_df) here shows the "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'"
```

I think the issue is with the function processdata(data_df).If anyone know what exactly the issue?

Comment: Your processdata() function does not return your data, so when calling data_df=processdata(data_df) you basically return nothing to data_df. Since the processdata() function does not alter the data, you don't need to call data_df=processdata(data_df), but you can just call processdata(data_df).

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not returning anything, just printing intermediate operations. And you are assigning that **nothing** to your dataframe **data_df**, hence it is not a dataframe any more. Use **return data_df** outside of **upper for loop**, defining what is the output that is need to be assigned to **data_df** later.